# Django Call Python Function From Query

Tags: django

When I querying a Model in Django, I want to create a custom field (using "extra" function) which may use as a sorting field.  For example,

```
result = foo_model.objects.filter(active=True).extra(select={'cal_field': pythonFunction()}).extra(order_by=['cal_field'])
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Can I create a field which calling a Python function inside "extra"?
2. If it can, how can I pass the current row into the function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What would your "Python function" do *exactly*? In most cases this wouldn't make sense as the query needs to be done in the database, not in Python. But most likely your functionality can be translated to actual db calls.

Comment: Actually I tried to create a function as property inside a Model.  The function can calculate the result which I expected but if I use this property in order_by clause it show error.  What I want is to calculate a result and I can use this result for sorting in the result set.

Comment: Well as I just said, you can't use Python functions like that, a query is done in the database. Which is why we need to know what the function *does*, so we can tell you how to translate it into an actual query.

Comment: I have 2 tables with Master / Details relation.  I want to have a list of Master table plus 2 calculated columns which are sum up from the Details rows of related Master record. The 2 calculated column may be used to as the sorting key and used for filtering the records. e.g. filter if calculated field value greater than a given parameter.